# test class for get task records from zoho crm using apex?

Tags: apex, unit-test, callout

```
            HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        
            req.setEndpoint('https://accounts.zoho.in/oauth/v2/token?refresh_token='+reftoken+'&client_id='+client_Id+'&client_secret='+client_secret+'&grant_type=refresh_token');
            req.setMethod('POST');
            HttpResponse res = ht.send(req);
            Map<String, Object> results = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
            if(res.getStatusCode() == 200){
                acctoken = (String)results.get('access_token');
                
                request.setEndpoint('https://www.zohoapis.in/crm/v2/Leads?fields=Full_Name&fields=Email&fields=Last_Activity_Time');
                request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + acctoken);
                request.setMethod('GET');
                response = http.send(request);
                if(response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                    deserialized = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
                }
            }

List<task> taskList = New List<task>();
        
        Set<String> leadName = new Set<String>();
        for(Object m2 : (List<Object>) deserialized.get('data')){
            Map<String, Object> leadFields = (Map<String, Object>)m2;
            String fullName = (String)leadFields.get('Full_Name');            
            leadName.add(fullName);
                   
        }            
        Map<String, Lead> IdToLeadMap = new Map<String, Lead>();
        leadList = [Select id, Name From Lead WHERE Name IN :leadName];
        system.debug(leadList);
        for (Lead ld : leadlist) {
            IdToLeadMap.put(ld.Name, ld);
        }
        
        for(Object m2 : (List<Object>) deserialized.get('data')){
            Map<String, Object> leadFields = (Map<String, Object>)m2;
            String id = (String)leadFields.get('id');
            String fullName = (String)leadFields.get('Full_Name');
            String lastActivityTime = (String)leadFields.get('Last_Activity_Time');   
            if(lastActivityTime != null){
                
                Http https = new http();
                HttpRequest requests = new HttpRequest();
                    
                requests.setEndpoint('https://www.zohoapis.in/crm/v2/leads/'+id+'/activities');
                requests.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accToken);
                requests.setMethod('GET');
                HttpResponse responses = https.send(requests);
                if(responses.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                    if(leadList.size() > 0){
                        Map<String, Object> deserializeds = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(responses.getBody());
                                                    
                        for(Object m21 : (List<Object>) deserializeds.get('data')){
                            Map<String, Object> leadField = (Map<String, Object>)m21;
                            String ActivityType = (String)leadField.get('Activity_Type');
                            if(ActivityType == 'Tasks'){
                                Task tasks = new Task();
                                if (!String.isEmpty(fullName) && IdToLeadMap.containsKey(fullName)) {
                                    tasks.whoId = IdToLeadMap.get(fullName).Id;
                                }
                                tasks.Priority = (String)leadField.get('Priority');
                                tasks.Status = (String)leadField.get('Status');
                                tasks.Subject = (String)leadField.get('Subject');
                                tasks.Description = (String)leadField.get('Description');
                                    
                                string dueDate = (String)leadField.get('Due_Date');
                                Date actDate = Date.valueOf(dueDate);
                                tasks.ActivityDate = actDate;
                                    
                                string crtDate = (String)leadField.get('Created_Time');
                                Date dt = Date.valueOf(crtDate);
                                tasks.CreatedDate = dt;
                                    
                                taskList.add(tasks);
                                system.debug(tasks);
                            } 
                        }
                           
                    }else{
                        system.debug('No Lead Found');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        try{
            Insert taskList;
        }catch(exception e){
            system.debug(e);
        }
        return response;
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Please read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and perhaps take the [tour] before you [edit] your question to show what you have tried and where you are stuck. This is not a free coding service and we look to help people how show some effort.